# How to Count the total sum of a numeric values that are part of a text string inside a cell

Tags: excel, vba, text-processing

I have been struggling with a problem I thought would be easy to solve, and would really appreciate some assistance.
I have one table containing only one Column and 65 Rows.
The values inside the cells are text strings of different length. See the values of tow cell Examples here:

Cell (1,2): GammelStreet 1 (1Watt) 400KJellingeStreet 1 (2Watt)700KKagsaakollegiet 1 (1Watt) 400KSibeliusStreet 13 (2Watt) 700KSydfrontStreet 77 (1Watt) 400KValby langStreet 240 (2Watt) 700KLyngbyStreet 307 (1Watt) 400KByglandsStreet 16 (1Watt) 400KEmdrupStreet 79 (1Watt) 400KBrolaeggerstraede 6 (1Watt) 400KMorescosStreet 14 (2Watt) 700K

Cell (2,2): EgilsStreet 4 (3Watt) 1000KBispeStreet 23 (1Watt) 400KEmma gads Street 10 (3Watt) 1000KMusvaageStreet 6 (1Watt) 400KGalathea Koen (3Watt) 1000KFarverStreet 10 (1Watt) 400KaarhusStreet 128a (2Watt) 700KMargretheholmsStreet 48 (3Watt) 1000KNoerre voldStreet 102 (1Watt) 400KGammelStreet 1 (2Watt+1Joule) 900KBorgerStreet 1 (4Watt) 1400KKnabrostraedet 1A (1Watt) 400KNoerrebroStreet 78 (1Watt) 400KFrederiksundsStreet 84a (2Joule) 500K

Cell (3,2): FredericiaStreet 14 (2Watt) 700KMariendalsStreet 65 (3Watt + 1Joule) 1400KHaspeKogen 2 (4Watt) 1400KKloevermarksStreet 50 (3Joule) 800KHorsevaenget 33 (2Watt) 700KPeter holms Street 4 (2Joule+1Watt) 1000KValby langStreet 240 (2Watt) 700KSkoleStreet 13b (2Watt) 700KParosStreet 1 (3Watt) 1000KBorgerStreet 30 (3Watt) 1000KLavendelstraede (2Watt) 700KPilegaardsStreet 17 (1Watt) 400KHorsevaenget 11 (2Watt) 700KHelmsStreet 22 (3Watt) 1000K MargretheholmsStreet 48 (2Watt) 700KFrimesterStreet 44 (1Watt) 400KTycho brahes alle 38 (1Watt) 400KVigerslev alle 168 (2Watt) 700KSankelmarksStreet 10 (1Joule) 400KMaageStreet 58 (2Watt+1Joule) 1000KGravervaenget 11 (2Watt) 700K

I need to make the sum of all the "Watt" values, "Joule" values, and "xxyyK" values in each row, and write the result in new column for each row.
For the examples above the result for Cell (1,2):  would be, Watt = 15 and Joule = 0 and "xxyyK" = 5600;
and for Cell (2,2): Watt = 26 and Joule = 3 and  "xxyyK" = 8500;
and for Cell (3,2): Watt = 37 and Joule = 8 and  "xxyyK" = 16500;

Comment: A regex-based approach might be appropriate here: https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-regex-guide/

Answer (score 0):

> for Cell (2,2): Watt = 26 and Joule = 3 and **"xxyyK" = 8500**

I don't know how to get `"xxyyK" = 8500`, because I thought `"xxyyK" = 9900` ?

> for Cell (3,2): **Watt = 37** and Joule = 8 and "xxyyK" = 16500

I don't know how to get `"Watt" = 37`, because I thought `"Watt" = 40` ?

Anyway, maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Dim txt As String
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim xxyyK As Long
Dim watt As Long
Dim joule As Long
Dim pl As Long
Dim wt As Long
Dim jl As Long

For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
watt = 0: joule = 0: xxyyK = 0: pl = 0: wt = 0: jl = 0
txt = cell.Value
For cnt = 1 To Len(txt)
    If Mid(txt, cnt, 1) = "(" Then
        For i = cnt To Len(txt)
            If Mid(txt, i, 1) = "K" Then
                x = Mid(txt, cnt + 1, i - cnt - 1)
                xxyyK = xxyyK + Trim(Split(x, ")")(1))
                
                    pl = InStr(x, "+")
                    wt = InStr(UCase(x), UCase("watt"))
                    jl = InStr(UCase(x), UCase("joule"))
                    
                    If pl <> 0 Then
                        If wt > jl Then watt = watt + Mid(x, pl + 1, wt - pl - 1): joule = joule + Trim(Split(UCase(x), UCase("joule"))(0))
                        If wt < jl Then joule = joule + Mid(x, pl + 1, jl - pl - 1): watt = watt + Trim(Split(UCase(x), UCase("watt"))(0))
                    Else
                        If wt <> 0 Then watt = watt + Trim(Split(UCase(x), UCase("watt"))(0))
                        If jl <> 0 Then joule = joule + Trim(Split(UCase(x), UCase("joule"))(0))
                    End If
                    
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Watt = " & watt & ", Joule = " & joule & ", xxyyK = " & xxyyK
Next cell

End Sub
```

The sub have 3 loops.

1. Loop to each cell with the text
2. Loop to each character in the text and check if the char is "("
3. if the char is "(" then it loop start from this char until it find char "K"

Once it found char "(" and char "K", it extract the characters in between as variable x. For example : `2Watt)700`, `3Watt + 1Joule) 1400`, `2Joule+1Watt) 1000`, etc.

Then it get the xxyyK value (and sum it) via SPLIT function.

Then it get the position of "+" (if any) as variable pl, get the position of "watt" (if any) as variable wt and get the position of "joule" (if any) as variable jl.

Then it check if pl <> 0 (so, there is a "+" sign in variable x)
if yes, then it get the value of the watt and the joule (and sum it) via MID function.
if not, then it get the value of the watt and the joule (and sum it) via SPLIT function.

The result from the example is put on column B :
[image]

Please note : the code assumed that there will always be char "(" and char ")". And the watt value (if any) and the joule value (if any) will always be inside "(" and ")" .... and there will always a value for xxyyK after char ")" (ended with char "K").

Comment: Dear Tim Williams, thank you very much for you solution, it looks realy good and promissing. I have not tried it it on my data, but I'm sure it will work, since it works on the 3 rows of data, then it should also work on the whole data work sheet. If I get any problem, is it ok to write to ?

Comment: Dear Tim Williams, I did tried it on my data, there was som issues due to iregularity in the data in som of the cells, which I adjustet according to the data in the most of the other cells, and then the code did the job perfectly :). Thanks again for your solution. Ther is two things that I dont understand in the code, first one is the argument (1)/(0) inside the function Trim, what is the use of this? The second one is why you convert the value for x, Watt and Joule to uppercase inside the IF statements?

Comment: The x variable value in the loop gives result something like this : (a) _2Watt)700_ , (b) _3Watt + 1Joule) 1400_. So I assume that the position for the xxyyK is always after ")" char.

To get value after ")", I use split function which is to "cut" the value with char ")". 

From the (a) example, "the left" (or the first ---> the identifier is 0) result is _2Watt and the right (or the second one ---> the identifier is 1 ) is _700_.

so in example (a), `Split(x, ")")(1)` will give result "_700_", `Split(x, ")")(0)` will give result "_2Watt_".

Comment: But I see your example data that after ")" char there maybe a blank space like in example (b), so I use Trim function to remove the space. From example (b), `Split(x, ")")(1)` will give result " _1400_" (there is a blank space before number 1). So the `Trim(Split(x, ")")(1))` give result "_1400_". For your second question, because I think the split function is case sensitive. For example, if the string data contains "watt" which sometimes with capital "W" sometimes with just "w". (continue)

Comment: Since I never know the text "watt" data will be with capital "W" or not, so I just make the whole x value with capital and the "watt" is also all capital letter ---> `Split(UCase(x), UCase("watt")`. But if you are sure that the data for the "watt" and "joule" text will always be like this "Watt" and "Joule", then you can just write `Split(x,"Watt")` or `split(x,"Joule")`.

Comment: For you to play around, there is a data string something like this "aaabcccDDD". You know that to get just the "DDD" value it will always be after "bccc". But you never know that the "bccc" text data will be "Bccc" or "bccc". In the macro sub, let's have the string data as x variable ---> `x = "aaabcccDDD"`. Then `v1 = Split(UCase(x), UCase("bccc"))(1)` and then `v2 = Split(x, "bccc")(1)`. With the data mentioned above, both v1 and v2 gives a correct result. But if you change the x variable into `x = "aaaBcccDDD"`, v2 will throw you an error.

Comment: have a real nice day, because you made my day with you graete help.